# I'm trying to get the document from the index in elasticsearch using Scala, but get the error

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, sbt

**Code of Getting Document**

Herr i have a case class User having some Attributes and have index "firstindex", i want to get the document on the bases of "id"

```
    import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.{GetRequest, GetResponse}
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

class GetIndex {

  def Getting(): Unit = {

    val esClient = ElasticSearchConnection.getClient
    val request: GetRequest = new GetRequest("firstindex", "1")

    val response: CompletableFuture[GetResponse[User]] = esClient.get(request, classOf[User])
    println(response)

  }
}
```

**Error**

```
   constructor GetRequest in class GetRequest cannot be accessed in class GetIndex from class GetIndex
val request: GetRequest = new GetRequest("firstindex", "1")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What don't you understand about these errors?

Comment: Thank you. I have update the error can you check it again

Comment: [GetRequest](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0/org/elasticsearch/action/get/GetRequest.html) doesn't seem to have a public constructor that would take two arguments.

Comment: thank you the issue has been resolved , yes the issue was in constructor of GetRequest.